# Kickoff and Krunner to search with less than 3 chars in search field?

Tags: kubuntu, search, krunner, kickoff

Both Krunner and Kickoff in Kubuntu return a list of found items after the user has entered at least three characters in the search field.

Usage on Synapse shows that returning a list after one character onwards is faster and efficient.

I would like Kickoff and Krunner to behave similarly, by making the return a list of items after entering the first character in their search field.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I do not know the answer but you can ask somebody on #kde channel. There is an IRC client for kde called Konversation or you can use freenode web browser client.

Comment: Would you take no as an answer? Apparently, minimum 3 characters is by design and you can probably only change it by building from source.

Comment: @jokerdino: then the answer is not really no, is it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***No, this settings can't be changed in default setup***. Krunner and Kickoff are designed to display search suggestion after at least 3 letters in input.  So, you can't change them because there is not configuration option to do so.

- [See this Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_Workspaces#KRunner) about Krunner.
- Also see [this documentation in userbase.kde.org](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner) which says, krunner requires at least 3 letters to be typed to match for a partial search.

[A bug report was filed](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=252675) against this behavior in https://bugs.kde.org, though it's status is still (7-9-2012) unconfirmed, the first response was

> As Plasma developers (somehow understandable) won‘t remove the 3 letters restricton, at least make it more obvious that it won‘t search bevore you‘ve entered at least 3 letters

So, it seems KDE developers are not willing to change this behavior. I think the only option is to change it yourself and then re-compile.

<sup>Note that, both Krunner and Kickoff was designed in this way</sup>

Comment: Hi Anwar. Thanks for your answer. I hesitated to give you the bounty because I had hoped to get an explicit answer as to how achieve what I want. In this case, how to change this in the code and recompile. So if you have any knowledge to share regarding this, would you be so kind to update your answer accordingly? Thanks again.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks. I'll try my best to give you at least some hints about this. If that is not possible, i'll inform you that too. Actually, I was looking for this feature too.

Comment: @Benjamin It seems I cannot give you any hints on that. (Still now, cause I am sort of busy). I suggest you to ask an question on the site. I hope, someone might answer the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Synapse, which tries to match items based on any input, Kickoff and Krunner are designed to match after you've inserted enough information to match with.

My suggestion would be to report a bug against the two as a wishlist item, since there are currently no options (that I know of), that allow you to change this.